# Algorithm style in latex

Tags: algorithms

I want to produce an algorithm style such that it is centered on the page, numbered and also that the horizontal lines do not extend unnecessarily as shown in the image. Is there any way using the algorithm package?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us what you have tried so far? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: The algorithms package separates the formatting from the float environment, allowing more control over margins etc.

Comment: I use the package algorithm2e, as it is quite flexible. The resulting floats can be placed at will.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun (after 15 minutes) I hope that this MWE is the same (without the mistakes of symbols) of your figure.....

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Gradient Descent}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Gradient Descent}{$\{(\mathbf{X}_i,Y_i)\}_{i\in \text{train}},Ep,\eta,\lambda,\alpha,\mathbf{w}_0$}
    \State $\mathbf{w}\leftarrow \mathbf{w}_0.$
    \For{$i \in\{1,\ldots Ep\}$}
    \State $\mathbf{w}\leftarrow \mathbf{w}-\eta(\nabla_{\mathbf{w}}MSE(c_{\mathbf{w}})+\lambda\mathbf{w})+\alpha\Delta(\mathbf{w}).$
    \EndFor
    \State{\textbf{Return} \textbf{w}.}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I use `\documentclass{ieeeaccess}` class, 1st procedure line did not fit into the first line,  is there any way to change font size or spacing slightly to make it fit?

Comment: @alper Can you ask a new question with your minimal working example, please?